# Live testing of websites

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder if there is any website application on where i can test my css, javascript and html pages in IE 6.0 - 8.0, Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari to see them live.

Comment: You can use http://browsershots.org/ to view what the website looks like on many browsers, however you can't test it live.

Comment: Why not install them all? It's a bother for sure, but a one-time bother with installation gets you the test platform, on your local machine (-> negligible latency).

Comment: @Piskvor It's not trivial to run multiple versions of ie though, unless he's using windows 7 or wine+ies4linux under linux.

Comment: @flesk: I didn't say it was trivial, but it's a one-off task. Took me a few hours and several virtual machines, **once**, and I am able to test in all IEs ever since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross browser teting of web application is possible in [Browserling](http://browserling.com/). You can test your javascripts using [Testling](http://testling.com/).

Comment: this was what i need, thanks. On spoon i need to install, this is free.

Answer (score 0):

General problem are occur in IE6.0 - 8.0 and safari so you should test in these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try spoon for this and you can test you sites how they behave on various browsers without having to install all the browsers
http://spoon.net/Apps/

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with [testling](https://ci.testling.com/) now there is a tool that allows you to get started with it as quickly as possible.

It's [testlingify](https://github.com/thlorenz/testlingify) which creates testling hooks on your repo on github and adds a testling browser config to your package.json.

Therefore to get started with testling in your project all you need to do is:

```
npm install -g testlingify
```

Then from inside your local github repository:

```
testlingify
```

**Note:** When you run it for the first time, you'll have to edit the generated config in order to include you github username and password.

Test the github hook via:

```
testlingify test
```

Print the testling badge to include in your readme via:

```
testlingify badge
```